# GLSurfaceView onPause uncleared frame remains behind

Tags: android, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I'm having an issue with rendering on GLSurfaceView. If I **QUICKLY** onPause/onResume the app *sometimes* I end up with some leftover uncleared frame, which I cannot clear or get rid of..

> easiest way to reproduce would be to press App Overview or Home button
> on navigation panel and then immediately reopen the app by pressing on
> the task preview)

The `onDrawFrame(gl: GL10)` is called with `gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` and I tried with `gl.glClearColor(0F, 0F, 0F, 0F)` too. But it only works for the current objects, the shadow from before I cannot get rid of.. I just cannot seem to reach that surface anymore.

[image]

This is not happening everytime, if I slowly onPause/onResume the app there will be no "shadows".

Here is the link to my [sample Android project](https://github.com/ardovic/Car-Movement-Simulation), where this issue can be reproduced. It's rather basic, so maybe you'd like to take a look at the code (`engine/Renderer.kt` & `MainActivity.kt`).

My main goal is to eliminate the possibility of getting these "shadows" on rendered frame from before onPause. I'm open to any suggestions, any answer, even if it's a workaround/lifehack. It just has to remove these leftowers.

Comment: @help no, unfortunately not